# Paypal checkout integration in native mobile without Braintree

Tags: android, ios, paypal

I have a requirement to integrate the paypal integration in native apps (iOS and android). I have braintree sdk option because paypal sdk is deprecated now for new inplementation.

iOS: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK

Android: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK

please refer important section.

can anyone send me the link or any sample for on time payment using paypal. this implementation will be for china.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I have been facing same problem for a month  .

Comment: @NirzonPop did you try using browser ?

Comment: Same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

**Past:** The two PayPal-xxx-SDKs you linked to are old and deprecated, no longer supported. End of life is Dec 8, 2020

**Present:** PayPal via Braintree iOS/Android SDKs are the current supported solutions: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/braintree-integration/

**Future:** A new Native PayPal SDK may become available at some point over the next year (2021)